# Selecting numbers into array and then looping over them

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to populate an array with numbers (it is the ID column of the table) and then loop over said array calling a stored procedure.

I am having trouble figuring out how to declare an array in which I won't know the size of until runtime and then populating it.

Currently, I have the following:

```
declare 
    type idArray is table of number index by pls_integer;
  theIdArray idArray;
begin

  select id into theIdArray from table_name_here where report_id = 3449;
end;
```

This is not working, but I don't know why. I then also need to loop through my array of numbers and call a stored procedure. Something like the following:

```
for i in theIdArray.FIRST..theIdArray.LAST LOOP
  stored_proc_here(i);
END LOOP;
```

Can someone give me some insight on to how to accomplish this. What I have so far has been derived from examples I sorta-kinda understood.

Comment: try replacing the `into` clause with `bulk collect into`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code fails because you are using clause `into`. For filling collections use  `bulk collect into` instead.

```
declare 
    type idArray is table of number index by pls_integer;
  theIdArray idArray;
begin

  select id bulk collect into theIdArray from table_name_here where report_id = 3449;
end;
```

Comment: I added the for loop after the select and I am getting the this error `PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'I'`. I am not sure why it is also capitalizing the 'I' in the error since it is lower case as well, but I know that isn't the reason for the error.

Comment: sorry, the error is because of `(i.id)`. If you use `theIdArray.FIRST..theIdArray.LAST` then you reference the object. Use `i` instead `i.id`

Comment: Just a side note on iterating collections: If `theIdArray` can be empty, you should iterate using `for i in 1 .. theIdArray.COUNT` and reference using `theIdArray(i)` instead of using `first`/`last`. This will allow the loop to skip instead of throwing an index out of bounds error.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is looping it could be just as easy to use a cursor loop.

```
declare
    cursor Ids is
        select ID from table_name_here where report_id = 3449;
...
for Report in Ids loop
    stored_proc_here( Report.ID );
end loop;
```

You don't have to worry about explicit opening, closing, fetching, allocating or deallocating. All that is handled by the loop.